# How is qsort able to take in any array types and sort it?

Tags: arrays, c, function, comparison, qsort

qsort has the following function protype

```
void qsort(
    void*  _Base,
    size_t _NumOfElements,
    size_t _SizeOfElements,
    _CompareFunction
    );
```

How is it possible that it is able to sort any array types (int, double, char, etc.)?
How does qsort know the type of array that I am asking it to sort?

Comment: The [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort#Example) in the documentation should answer your question.

Comment: It doesn't know the types. The arguments define the abstract array, and crucially a function that makes the comparison: your own function where the knowledge is applied. A callback function.

Comment: `qsort` doesn't need to know the type, just the size. Which you tell it in parameter 3 and it uses to figure out which memory locations bound each element to pass to the comparator. Your comparator does the rest, casting the `void *` to the correct type.

Answer (score 2):

It is due to the comparison function that casts void pointers to required types when it compares elements of the array.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp( const void *px, const void *py )
{
    int x = *( const int * )px;
    int y = *( const int * )py;

    return ( y < x ) - ( x < y );
}

int main( void ) 
{

    int a[] ={5, 3, 1, 9, 8, 2, 4, 7};
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    qsort( a, N, sizeof( *a ), cmp );
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
5 3 1 9 8 2 4 7 
1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9
```

As you can see within the comparison function `cmp` the passed pointers are casted to the required type.

```
int x = *( const int * )px;
int y = *( const int * )py;
```

To traverse the array the function `qsort` uses the pointer arithmetic the following way. Initially the pointer `_Base` points to the first element of the passed array. To move for example the pointer to the i-th element of the array it does something like the following

```
void *ith_element_ptr = ( char * )_Base + i * _SizeOfElements;
```

Comment: Yes, because you *tell* `qsort` with your user-defined function which makes the comparison, as you are the only one who knows the structure of each element in the array that you pass, and in what *sequence* to sort it. In some cases, it will be an array of `struct` and you might consider more than one member: if the major members are equal, compare other members. In the simple case of an integer array, this function will control how to sort in ascending, or descending order.